# Check the office License Status from batch file

Tags: batch-file, scripting, office-2013

I am making a batch file that can check to see if your office 2013 has a icense or not.

```
for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%a in (
'cscript "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office15\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus ^| find "License Status:"' 

) do set "licenseStatus=%%a"
if /i "%licenseStatus%"=="--- LICENSED ---" (
Echo I am Licensed
Pause
EXIT
) Else (
Echo I am NOT Licensed
Pause
EXIT
)
```

But every time I run this code it all way come back with a I am NOT Licensed. I have check it be running the ospp.vbs script myself it say ---License---. I would like to know where I  when wrong with this. Thinking it in the path for this script. I am talking about (%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office15\OSPP.VSB /Dstatus) Any help you can give me would like a great help. Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: From what I've seen in Google searches and in your explanation, you need to check against `---LICENSED---` instead of `--- LICENSED ---` - note the spaces in your code that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thank you for your info. I have try it with and withot spaces.  Plus have try it just using Licensed.. Didn't work for me. But, thank you for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `/I` flag with `find`. Alternatively, you need to search for the string "LICENSE STATUS". Right now, you're doing a case-sensitive search for "License Status," which doesn't appear with that exact capitalization anywhere in the output of OSPP.vbs.

Also, you need to get rid of the spaces in "--- LICENSED ---" because the actual output has no spaces.

[image]

```
@echo off

:: The below directory is for users with a 64-bit operating system
:: 32-bit users can find the script in "%ProgramFiles%"\Microsoft Office\Office15\OSPP.vbs"
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%a in ('cscript "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office15\OSPP.VBS" /dstatus ^| find /i "License Status:"') do (
    set "licenseStatus=%%a"
)

if /i "%licenseStatus%"=="---LICENSED---" (
    Echo I am Licensed
) Else (
    Echo I am NOT Licensed
)

pause
```

Comment: @user2559533 - Sure thing! If my answer helped you, please click the check mark next to my answer.