# Command line query for valid Visual Studio license?

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, command-line, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way, via command line, that I can determine if a particular installation of Visual Studio 2017 has a valid license or not? Something short of actually executing Msbuild.exe and catching an error message?

We have a number of developer VMs that are all identical, and all have both VS 2017 Pro and Enterprise installed. Our developers are variously licensed for one or the other. Some machines are exclusively used by a single developer, some are shared, and some developers may work on multiple VMs.

Then we have build scripts, as .bat files, that will execute Msbuild to compile a series of VS solutions. Of course the version of Msbuild that works will be in one path or the other, or maybe they'll both be licensed. But the same build script has to work on every machine regardless.  Something of the form:

```
if ProProductKeyIsActive (
  set MsBuildPath = "...\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Msbuild.exe"
) else (
  set MsBuildPath = "...\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Msbuild.exe"
)
```

Thanks!

Comment: So that is all pseudo code I assume because not a single line has correct syntax.

Comment: @Squashman - the `) else (` is correct :)

Comment: Yes. Haha. It's not intended to be real code, merely the gist of the conditional I'd use

Comment: It sounds like you are conflating the issue of figuring out where MSBuild is installed with figuring out it has a valid license. You can use the tool [VsWhere.exe](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere/wiki) which is installed in a common location on all machines to locate the latest version of MSBuild that is installed.

Comment: Not conflating. I'm trying to make clear that I know where MsBuild is installed, that in fact two versions of it are installed, but that I'm trying to figure out which one will be properly licensed.

Comment: What about a user environment setting?

Answer (score 1):

> Command line query for valid Visual Studio license?

AFAIK, there is no such a way, via command line, that you can determine if a particular installation of Visual Studio 2017 has a valid license or not.

As we know, we could to know the registry key containing the license information from:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Licenses\5C505A59-E312-4B89-9508-E162F8150517
```

We could use the batch file to check if we have this registry value to determine if Visual Studio 2017 has a license, like:

[Check the office License Status from batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021545/check-the-office-license-status-from-batch-file)

but it seems we could not to know if this license is valid.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. Needing to know if the license is valid or not is the problem :(

but thanks

Answer (score 1):

(Does not exactly answers the question because amounts to trying to run the tools and catching an error message).

A **hacky** way of testing if the license has expired or if it is still valid is to check the return code of the command `devenv.com /Build`.

If the license is still valid the command `devenv.com /Build` will return `0` and display the "usage" help message, whereas if the license has expired it will return `1` and display a message similar to:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 version 16.11.13.
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. Tous droits réservés.

La licence de Visual Studio a expiré.
La période d'évaluation de ce produit est terminée.
```

Tested with Visual Studio 2019.